# canvg and highcharts how to include chart legend and keep the chart size?

Tags: canvas, highcharts, canvg

I'm trying to use canvg to draw a highchart inside a canvas.

the problem I have is that the chart legends dont appear in the canvas and also the size and quality is reduced.
[image]

```
$('#container').highcharts({

            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },

            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
            }]

        });

    function exportChart() {
        var svg = canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'), getSVG(), { ignoreDimensions: true });
    }

    function getSVG() {
        debugger
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var svg = chart.getSVG();
        return svg;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you remove option `ignoreDimensions: true` it works good, I think: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/qDmhV/148/

If you want to have the same size for chart - you need to have canvas container the same width and height as for chart.

Edit:

- with disabled ignoreDimensions:
  [image: with disabled ignoreDimensions]
- without disabled ignoreDimensions:
  [image: without disabled ignoreDimensions]

Comment: Uploaded images with different result when enabling/disabling ignoreDimensions.