# High Chart to Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas, highcharts

I'm trying to convert highchart into canvas, so that i can set it to img src.

This is my code

**Javascript:**

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById('container')], {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(canvas);
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = data;
        document.getElementById('image').appendChild(image);
    }
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="canvas">
    <p>Canvas :</p>
</div>
<div id="image">
    <p>Image :</p>
</div>
```

I'm not able to get the highchart data as canvas, please help me to solve this

Comment: How about using Canvg? It allows to translate SVG to Canvas. From [FAQ](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/faq.html) - SVG images aren't rendered.

Comment: @PawełFus can u please suggest sample code, how to do this?

Comment: @speeday125: can you provide a sample jsfiddle with a basic chart / html structure?

Comment: @NicolasR http://jsfiddle.net/clockworked247/c2Dp2/14/ i'm trying to get image of pie chart

Comment: See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332247/canvg-and-highcharts-how-to-include-chart-legend-and-keep-the-chart-size there is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fusher/qDmhV/148/

Comment: I managed to get it working on button click also, but not on chart load.. still looking for the solution. When I use the callback on the initial method, it's looping :/

Comment: @PawełFus thanks for the link you provided, it helped me a lot solving this, now its working perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Export part

The **export is easy to handle** using `canvg` library (as provided by highcharts samples and other SO questions, like the one provided in comment [canvg and highcharts how to include chart legend and keep the chart size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18332247/canvg-and-highcharts-how-to-include-chart-legend-and-keep-the-chart-size)).

Assuming you already got a `canvas` item in your html:

Scripts referenced:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://canvg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/canvg.js"></script>
```

Javascript functions:

```
function exportChart() {
    var svg = canvg(document.getElementById('canvas'), getSVG(), {
        //ignoreDimensions: true
    });
}

function getSVG() {
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var svg = chart.getSVG();
    return svg;
}
```

Working fiddle with this function called by a button: http://jsfiddle.net/c2Dp2/231/

---

### Script execution

**The main problem is:** how/where/when should we execute this to get it working?

In fact, there seems not to be any `complete` event triggered when **all** animations are executed. I tried the following:

- Using `Load` event (see [Highcharts documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.events.load)) : the script is looping, despite the face that the event is supposed to fire when:

> Fires when the chart is finished loading

- Using `animation complete` in `plotOptions.series`: this event is triggered several times ==> cannot be used for this purpose
- Using the callback of the `highchart` function: the script is also looping here, even if the callback is only called one.

This `ready` event problem has been already asked in highcharts forum, for example here: http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=10078 but I cannot find a way to use the samples they provided.

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to Paweł Fus (see comments on this answer): the function for export creates another chart, explaining why it is looping in our previous cases.

The flag `chart.userOptions.chart.forExport` is set to true when we call the export function, so we just have to filter in the callback to avoid looping.

Update fiddle: jsfiddle.net/c2Dp2/232

Comment: Thank you so much for answering and showing interest in this question, you are really awesome :)

Comment: Thanks for the +1/accept. I'm disappointed not finding a way to launch the script. A bad way would be to use a timer (based on the plotOptions.series.animation.duration parameter for example), but there are several drawbacks to this approach

Comment: Ow... I you just needed onclick, that's great (and in that case, it could have been a duplicate from an other question). I upvoted Pawel comments that put me on the right way

Comment: `getSVG()` creates another chart with another callback, which creates infinite loop. To prevent this just call `exportChart()` only when chart isn't created for exporting. You can check `chart.userOptions.chart.forExport` flag, see: http://jsfiddle.net/c2Dp2/232/

Comment: Thanks Pawel! I will update my answer with your item